# A question about Nozzle/Extension/Skirt Size

Tags: engines, engine-design

In many rocket engines i see that the thrust chamber and a small part of the nozzle are one piece.

 Does anyone knows if there's a formula which determines what portion of the nozzle is A ?
and how much is B ?

[image]

If possible I would like a reference to a chapter of a rocket book.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK it's related to the type of cooling used in the thrust chamber vs the nozzle extension, not any kind of "formula".

Comment: Structural and thermal strength of the nozzle dictates that. The "A" part is made out of the same stuff as the combustion chamber itself, and for the same reason. It is exposed to high temperature gas, massive radiant heat, and very high pressures. The "B" part of the nozzle is  much , *much* more benign environment, with pressures and heat flux a magnitude lower than in "A", thus it can be made out of weaker and more importantly *lighter* construction.